# How can i put multiple laravel api on one subdomain

Tags: laravel

Iam creating my portfolio this is my first time using laravel and what i want is to put all my project APIs on one subdomain. Currently i have 3 projects API

Comment: just create api route group for each api like api-1, api-2 and api-3 will solve your issue.

Comment: @umefarooq hi can you explain more? right now inside my subdomain has 3 folders for each Laravel projects i have

Comment: you have three different subdomains pointed to these folders or using just 1 subdomain for all these three folders